# Problems with Url.action

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I tried to `@Url.Action("Shelf", "Example")` form "Shelf" view but it does not seem to reload. It works if I right click and open in new tab/window. Also if I use it from "Shelf2" it works.

I also tried `@Url.Action("Shelf", "Example", new { id = "" })` but it does not work.
The calls are made from a popup msgbox. Why does this happen.

If I use `href=/Example/Shelf` it works.

Comment: did you wrap the href in single quotes?
like <a href='@Url.Action("Shelf", "Example")'>Link</a>

Comment: yes href is in single quotes, any other page call works but page being called from itself does not.

Comment: It is partial view? If yes, you should specifiy area of action explicity.

Comment: It is a partial view, where do I specify area of action.

Comment: Define _it works_ please. Do you want to generate the URL? or Do you want to to render the view from the URL?

Comment: I want render the view. It generates Url properly. but on click of button it does not load the page.

Comment: I think you want to have `Html.Action` instead. What button? could you show the code?

Comment: if I use href='/Example/Shelf' then it works. Problem is I want to know url.action does not work, I have used url.action throughout the code and want to keep consistency

Comment: you need to post more complete code, otherwise we can only assume, see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <p>
                        Want to see all your files? </p>
                    <p>

Comment: <a href='@Url.Action("Shelf2", "Example")' class="btn"><b class="caret-right"></b>Go
                            to My Shelf</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <p>
                        Would you like create new Shelf?</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href='@Html.Action("Shelf", "Example")' class="btn"><b
                            class="caret-right"></b>New Shelf</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: public ActionResult Shelf()
        {
            if (!SiteSession.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                return Login();
            }

            return View("Shelf");
        }

Comment: Hello everyone I checked with few other people it seems problem is due to the fact that page doesn't reload since there is no change in controller. Thank you for helping out please tell if you think there is any other way around. I know that redirect to action works.